# How to compile and emit Razor Class Library at runtime using roslyn?

Tags: c#, razor, roslyn

I can generate the c# code of some Asp.Net Core controllers at runtime, compile it, and get the dll file using Roslyn, and everything works fine.
The problem is I can't figure out how can I get the Razor Class Library as the out put of compilation.
I mean, I want to ad some CSHTML files to list of source code files, and get the RCL output.

Thanks.